# glmnet.ElastiNet:lambda_path argument

Tags: python, glmnet

I am learning from:

https://github.com/JWarmenhoven/ISLR-python/blob/master/Notebooks/Chapter%206.ipynb

and have issues with following code:

```
grid = 10**np.linspace(10,-2,100)

ridge3 = gln.ElasticNet(alpha=0, lambda_path=grid)
ridge3.fit(X, y)
```

What does lambda_path argument mean?
I am using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does lambda_path argument mean? I am using Python.

Here `lambda` has nothing to do with Python.

In Python, `lambda` is a function, which comes from lambda calculus.

In lasso and elastic-net regularization, `lambda` is a regularization penalty coefficient. In other words, it is a number.
And `lambda_path` is a sequence of numbers.
In the code example you given, the sequences is generated automatically.
And `ridge3.fit` will performance training for every number of the lambda sequence.

P.S. In Mathematics, to keep formula short so humans can write formula quickly,
Mathematics uses single letter variable name a lot without namespace prefix.
However, there are not so many letters, so conflicts occur.
Here both lambda calculus and regularization choose the Greek letter λ,
which may cause your confusion.